# Como self é utilizado?

Tags: javascript

Qual a especialidade de `self`, uma propriedade global que refere ao próprio objeto global?

```js
console.log(self === this, this.self === this,
    window.self === this, self.self === this);
```

Comment: Olá Matheus, apenas da sua pergunta ser mais antiga acabei por responder nesta [JavaScript - Diferença entre \`this\` e \`self\`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/201984/javascript-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-this-e-self) por isto estou votando como dup.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self), a notação `self` sozinha é útil quando se está trabalhando com [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker). Sei que minha resposta não está bem detalhada, mas creio que este link te colocará no caminho certo.

Comment: Era esse tipo de resposta que eu esperava. Só não consigo entender o porquê dela ser útil em relação à web workers.