# JavaScript - Diferença entre `this` e `self`

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de entender e ajudar a comunidade com uma informação.

Qual a diferença do uso de `this` e `self` no JavaScript?

Basicamente: O qué? Por quê utilizar? Como utilizar?

Comment: Quem quiser usar como referencia, dando os devidos créditos, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875767/difference-between-this-and-self-in-javascript

Answer (score 22, accepted):

O `this` pode ser qualquer coisa, depende de onde foi aplicado, ele é usado junto com *classes no JavaScript* e `prototype` para se referir ao objeto, se não for um objeto então podem ocorrer duas situações:

- Em navegadores this assume o valor de `window`
- No Node.js o this assume o valor de `global`

Por exemplo:

```js
function Foo() {
    console.log(String(this));
}

// Chama como função e exibe [object Window]
Foo();

// Chama como classe e exibe [object Object]
new Foo;
```

O `self` é equivalente ao `window.self` e é usado **somente em navegadores**, no caso com `self` você pega a janela/aba atual, ou frame/iframe atual e pode comparar com `parent` (mesmo que `window.parent`), o `parent` neste caso pega o escopo da página que é pai da atual se estiver em um `<iframe>` por exemplo, caso contrário `parent` e `self` terão o mesmo valor.

O valores que você pode usar para comparar a janela são:

- `window.self` retorna o objeto da janela atual
- `window.parent` retorna o objeto da janela pai se houver, caso contrário o valor será igual ao de `self`
- `window.top` retorna o objeto da janela acima de todas, por exemplo se uma página tiver um iframe chamado `#frame1` e este iframe tiver outro iframe chamado `#frame2`, então em `#frame2` usar `window.top` ele irá retornar o objeto página que embarcou o `#frame1`

Um exemplo interessante que você pode aplicar o `self` seria checar se um site externo esta embarcando alguma página sua, então fazer algo como:

```js
if (window.top !== window.self) {
    window.top.location.href = window.location.href;
}
```

Se a aba ou janela não for a mesma que `self` então é porque a sua página esta embarcada em outra página, podendo ser no seu site ou não, então o site que embarcou uma página sua será redirecionada para o seu site/página, claro que é apenas um código de exemplo, existem outras maneiras de bloquear o embarcar nos navegadores modernos, como por exemplo controlando `X-Frame-Options` ou `Content-Security-Policy`.

### Web Worker

Um detalhe importante é que em *Web Workers* também temos o [**`self`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/self), mas ele não acessa a janela, ele é usado semelhante ao `this`, mas ao invés de pegar o escopo de uma classe ou prototype, ele pega o escopo do *Web Worker* atual.

O `this` também pega o escopo do Worker, mas se o `this` estiver dentro de uma classe dentro do Worker ele não vai pegar o Worker, e sim o "objeto" da classe, por exemplo:

Na página:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var worker = new Worker('webworker.js');

worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    console.log('Worker respondeu: ', e.data);
}, false);

function sayHello()
{
    worker.postMessage('oi, tudo bem?'); // Envia mensagem ao werbworker.js
}

function sayTchau()
{
    worker.postMessage('tchau'); // Envia mensagem ao werbworker.js
}
</script>

<button onclick="sayHello()">Diga Oi!</button>
<button onclick="sayTchau()">Diga Tchau!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Dentro do `webworker.js`

```js
this.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    switch (e.data) {
        case 'oi, tudo bem?':
            this.postMessage('Tudo sim :)'); // Envia resposta para a página de "saudação"
            break;
        case 'tchau':
            this.postMessage('Tchau, até mais'); // Envia resposta para a página de "despedida"
            break;
    }
}, false);
```

Mas se fizer isto não vai funcionar, pois `this` não será mais o escopo do Worker:

```js
function Classe()
{
    this.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        switch (e.data) {
            case 'oi, tudo bem?':
                this.postMessage('Tudo sim :)'); // Envia resposta para a página de "saudação"
                break;
            case 'tchau':
                this.postMessage('Tchau, até mais'); // Envia resposta para a página de "despedida"
                break;
        }
    }, false);
}

new Classe;
```

O correto deverá ser:

```js
function Classe()
{
    self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        switch (e.data) {
            case 'oi, tudo bem?':
                self.postMessage('Tudo sim :)'); // Envia resposta para a página de "saudação"
                break;
            case 'tchau':
                self.postMessage('Tchau, até mais'); // Envia resposta para a página de "despedida"
                break;
        }
    }, false);
}

new Classe;
```

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento. A inclusão do exemplo em WebWorker foi top. Obrigado.

Comment: @BrunoHeringer atualizei a resposta ;)

Answer (score 4):

`self` é uma variável global declarada dentro do contexto dos navegadores, que referencia o chamado "objeto global". Em um ambiente de script de página web, o "objeto global" é o `Window`, e em um ambiente de Web Worker, o "objeto global" é o [`WorkerGlobalScope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope).

`this` é uma palavra da linguagem que referencia "o objeto a partir do qual a função atualfoi invocada". NO ENTANTO, quando o código atual não está dentro de nenhuma função, `this` referencia o "objeto global" (o mesmo do self).

```
function funcao() {
  console.log(this)
}
obj.funcao = funcao
obj.funcao(1) // "this === obj" true
console.log(this) // this === window
console.log(this === self) // true
```

Veja que isto de o `this` referenciar uma coisa quando dentro de uma função e outra quando não, é meio que uma "falha de projeto" do JavaScript -- não é legal `this` referenciar `Window`, pois isso gera confusão. Para remediar a bagunça, posteriormente criaram a variável `self`, que SEMPRE referencia o objeto global.

`self` não existe no contexto de um script no node.js (pois não é um padrão do javascript, mas apenas uma variável que a API dos navegadores disponibiliza). Para amenizar a bagunça, posteriormente criaram o `globalThis`, este sendo realmente um padrão da linguagem JavaScript, que é reservado pra referenciar o objeto global no contexto do script, independente da engine hospedeira.

*(engines hospedeiras: O navegador, o node.js, o cliente do League of Legends, etc).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis

(edit)
**Quando utilizar cada uma?**

Se você quer referenciar ao objeto global, utilize sempre `globalThis` ou `window`. Evite o `this`.

NO ENTANTO...

Note que `globalThis` é um recurso relativamente recente do JS, então ele pode não funcionar em navegadores pré-históricos. Se você está programando pra um navegador antigo e não está usando o babel, use outro tipo de referência direta, como o `window`.

Evite o `this` pra referenciar o objeto global pois causa confusão.

Use o `this` pra referenciar o contexto da classe do qual seu método está sendo invocado, como usual.