# Alterar cor da div em evento 'onclick' - JS

Tags: javascript

> Essa função 'Gerar quadrado' cria uma div com formato quadrado com a cor vermelha. O que eu tô tentando fazer é mudar a cor do quadrados quando eu clicar nele. (Não sei passar o elemento gerado como parâmetro na função, preciso de ajuda nisso também.)

Document


    Gerar Quadrado

```
</div>

<script>
    function gerarQuadrado() {
        var boxElement = document.createElement('div');
        boxElement.style.height = '100px';
        boxElement.style.width = '100px';
        boxElement.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
        boxElement.style.margin = '10px';
        boxElement.setAttribute('class', 'box');
        boxElement.setAttribute('onclick', 'mudarCor(self)');

        var divElement = document.querySelector('div#app');
        divElement.appendChild(boxElement);
    }

    function mudarCor(box) {
        var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        var color = "#";
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {   
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];  
        }
        this.box.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `self` não pode ser enviado como parâmetro para a função porque não tem a ver com o contexto. Veja o tópico abaixo:

- [JavaScript - Diferença entre `this` e `self`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/201984/8063)

O que você tem que enviar é o `this`, que irá referenciar o elemento clicado na função, que será atribuído à variável `box` que você colocou:

```
boxElement.setAttribute('onclick', 'mudarCor(this)');
```

E na função, não coloque o `this` antes do objeto `box`, porque o `box` não é uma propriedade do objeto `window`, que é referenciado pelo `this` na função:

```
box.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

**Veja:**

```js
function gerarQuadrado() {
     var boxElement = document.createElement('div');
     boxElement.style.height = '100px';
     boxElement.style.width = '100px';
     boxElement.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
     boxElement.style.margin = '10px';
     boxElement.setAttribute('class', 'box');
     boxElement.setAttribute('onclick', 'mudarCor(this)');

     var divElement = document.querySelector('div#app');
     divElement.appendChild(boxElement);
 }

 function mudarCor(box) {
     var letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
     var color = "#";
     for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {   
         color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];  
     }
     box.style.backgroundColor = color;
 }
gerarQuadrado();
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Tenta ao invés de você colocar "self" no método boxElement.setAttribute('onclick', 'mudarCor(self)');, coloque o "this" boxElement.setAttribute('onclick', 'mudarCor(this)');