# Como faço para retornar a propriedade de uma classe em um objeto de uma função?

Tags: javascript, objetos

```
class Servidor{
    constructor(ip, port){
        this.ip = ip
        this.port = port
        this.admin = true
    }
    getPropert(){
        return { // o erro está aqui
            this.port,
            this.admin,
            this.ip
        }
    }
}
```

O meu objetivo era fazer a função `getPropert` retornar um objeto com o valor das propriedades da classe, entretanto, me deparo com o seguinte erro:

```
   this.port, 
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

Comment: no lugar de `self.id` coloque `this.ip` e consequentemente nos outros.

Comment: ok, vou fazer isso.

Comment: Observei aqui, não era para ser self mesmo, todavia, mesmo com this, que se referencia a classse, ele dá erro de syntax.

Comment: Acredito que seja algum problema de escopo, mas não sei resolvê-lo.

Comment: é this para ter escopo na classe e faltou `return {'ip' : this.id}` ou `{...this}`, criando um objeto sem chaves ele está reclamando ...

Comment: muito obrigado, consegui pela seu comentário.

Comment: leitura recomendada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/201984/javascript-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-this-e-self

Comment: irei ler, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além de mudar de `self` para `this` [(escopo da classe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875767/difference-between-this-and-self-in-javascript) os itens no seu `construtor` o método `getPropert` é para retornar um objeto, e objeto em [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tem chave e valor e no caso da pergunta só tem valor precisa colocar:

```
{'ip': this.ip, 'port': this.port, 'admin': this.admin}
```

ou

```
{...this}
```

Exemplo minimo:

```js
class Servidor{
    constructor(ip, port){
        this.ip = ip
        this.port = port
        this.admin = true
    }   
    
    getPropert() {
      return {
        'ip': this.ip,
        'port': this.port,
        'admin': this.admin
      };
      // ou
      // return {...this}
    }
}

console.log(
  (new Servidor('192.168.0.1', 80)).getPropert()
);
```

Um outra explicação de `self` e `this`: [JavaScript - Diferença entre `this` e `self`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/201984/javascript-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-this-e-self)

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu o problema.